# Javascript: no idea why this solution works

Tags: javascript, prompt

Okay, I'm doing an exercise to learn Javascript, where I need to make a simple Sudoku app. There's a function to create the Sudoku field, and each little square is in a div with an id identifying the row number and column number.

Now the idea is that if a user clicks on an open field, a prompt appears asking him/her to enter a number. If the number is between 1 and 9, that number is then displayed inside the field.

I first invoked the function like this:

```
node.onclick=function(){fillNumber(this.id);};
```

This had the unexpected side-effect of **making the prompt box appear three times in a row** whenever a click was performed. Yet, it was clear that the first input by the user was accepted, stored and added to the div just like it was supposed to. The input from the second and third prompt box is simply lost.

I solved the problem by using the following invocation:

```
node.onclick=function(){if (parseInt(this.id) > 0) fillNumber(this.id);};
```

Yet I've no idea why this works (this is copied from a fellow student who did it this way, but doesn't know why). The value of `this.id` is always something like this: "11", "12", "13", "21", "22", ... So I don't even see the point of first parsing it to an int or checking whether it's bigger than 0. It always is both an int and bigger than 0 as far as I can see. Regardless, the code of the method itself didn't change and the method is invoked with the exact same argument value.

Here's the method fillNumber:

```
function fillNumber(id){
    var input = -1;
    do{
      input = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 9: ", ""));
    }while(input < 1 || input > 10);
    var i = parseInt(id/10), j = id%10;
    numbers[i][j] = input;
    var tekst = document.createTextNode(numbers[i][j]);
    document.getElementById(tekst).appendChild(tekst);
}
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Is there a possibility of hovering elements above each other? You just may be clicking through three elements in a row.

Comment: I'd say it has something to do with scoping, if you `console.log(this)` inside your `node.onclick=function(){fillNumber(this.id);};`, we could give you some more help.

Comment: We need to see more code. What is "node" in the line `node.onclick=...`? What is the surrounding code?

Comment: Also, if you can reproduce it on jsfiddle it would greatly help us to help you. I wrote [rough mockup](http://jsfiddle.net/JMvmp/) feel free to change it with the actual code.

Comment: This is most certainly not resposible for what you are experiencing but should `document.getElementById(tekst)` not be `document.getElementById(id)`?

Comment: @basilikum, not sure but may be he have a element named same as the variable. If not, then you are correct and he's a mistake.

Comment: @koen, whatever code you have posted is not enough to get the problem. though it's not related to your problem but suggestion; no need of calling your function like `function(){fillNumber(this.id);};`   just make it `fillNumber(this.id);`

Comment: @Rahul if he would just write `fillNumber(this.is)` then this function would be executed once and the result would be assigned to `onclick` which is probably not what he wants.

Comment: @Rahul: i've tried that approach to just write `fillNumber(this.id)`, but that doesn't work.  Wasn't sure why but @basilikum just answered it (thanks for that!)

@Shadow Wizard: tried to use the JSFiddle but somehow the dynamic html generation doesn't work there?  I'm not familiar with JSFiddle (though i have heard it mentioned before never played around with it), so might be doing something wrong.  The JS code for node = is there though [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JMvmp/)

@all: thanks a lot for the help!  Question answered by @Michael Sazonov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may suggest you to check whether there are elements upon each other - this might be the reason for three prompts in a row.

I guess the reason the other student wrote `parseInt(this.id)` is the same.
He tries to parse an `id` into an `int` to escape the other clicked elements, so he makes sure the id is a valid number.

Try to use next lines:

```
node.onclick=function(e){
    if( e.stopPropagation ) e.stopPropagation();
    if( e.preventDefault ) e.preventDefault();
    else e.returValue = false;
    fillNumber(+this.id);
}
```

Note the `+` at `+this.id` parses a string to an integer or a float.

Comment: `id` can't be the problem. As OP stated, issue is getting >1 prompts instead 1 and `ID` is getting used after user enters a input in the prompt.

Comment: `But, if an object has an empty id - it will be parsed as 0` - I think this is wrong. If an empty (or white space only) string is parsed to an integer, it becomes `NaN`.

Comment: Okay, thanks all for the feedback.  The answer by Michael Sazonov is where the problem lay.  The problem was that the html was dynamically generated and placed within a structure like this:
<div><div id = "numbers"><div id = "11></div<div id = "12"></div> and so on.  Therefore indeed without checking to see if the id is > 0 the prompt runs 3 times.

Comment: @Rahul my post isn't about the `id`